# JavaScript for Bootstrap dropdown sometimes works, sometimes doesn't

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, haml

So I'm using the Bootstrap dropdown menu like so:

```
%ul.hidden-xs.hidden-sm
  %li= link_to "LIBRARY", library_path
  %li= link_to "PRICING", plans_and_pricing_path
  %li.dropdown
    .dropdown-toggle{"aria-expanded" => "false", "aria-haspopup" => "true", "data-toggle" => "dropdown"}= link_to "#{current_user.first_name} <i class='fa fa-caret-down'></i>".html_safe, '#'
    %ul.dropdown-menu
      %li= link_to 'Edit profile', edit_user_registration_path(resource), class: 'user-nav-li'
      %li= link_to 'Referrals', referrals_path, class: 'user-nav-li'
  %li= link_to "LOG OUT", destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete
```

Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  I've tried looking at the elements in the inspector when the dropdown is clicked (on the times it's not working), and I can see the events triggering.  The `%li.dropdown` is supposed to have the `open` class added to it, and `aria-expanded` is supposed to change from `true` to `false`. This is what happens when it is working. However, when it's not working, the elements stay the same, but simply briefly highlight in the inspector (Chrome), as elements do when they're being changed.

This tells me the JS is loading, since it's at least responding to the click event. But nothing else happens.

I've tried looking for patterns. Refreshing sometimes fixes it, but other times triggers the problem. Sometimes navigating to a different page fixes it, but sometimes doesn't.  And none of the pages behave consistently.  I guess it shouldn't matter anyway, since it's in my navbar and that's on the application level.

I'm not sure what else to try. Everything seems pretty random.

Side note: I'm not a JavaScript pro

Comment: May be the `turbolinks` could be troubling you. Install `gem 'jquery-turbolinks'` and check.

Comment: this could be helpfull for you https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/issues/714

Comment: You're my hero, @Pavan.  `jquery-turbolinks` fixed my issue, along with a few others that I was using some disturbing workarounds for :)

Comment: Great! I will add it as an answer :)

Comment: Thanks for the link, @rob.  It was very interesting to read about the affects of using different ways of requiring/importing bootstrap and sprockets in css/js files. Could save me some headaches later on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said the culprit is `turbolinks`. Adding the gem `jquery-turbolinks` should solve the issue.

```
#Gemfile
gem 'jquery-turbolinks'
```

And run `bundle install`